# How to import and read ivt file in R

Tags: r, import

I am using the UNCTAD data which is supplied in *.ivt (Beyond 20/20 format) file. I don't know how to import that format into R. There is a special software to read this file it is known as Professional Browser is available [here](https://www.jodidata.org/gas/support/user-guide/how-to-read-ivt-beyond-2020-format-files.aspx).

A sample of the file is given [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D8-gfiPJpqEYPNRDr1lFCzCUZVvJ3edj/view?usp=sharing).

I use this browser and then copy paste the data. It has restrictions on number of rows to be copied. Hence, it is very tiring process. If it can be imported then it would give a huge boost to study UNCTAD data.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deal with *.ivt files in Python. I didn’t find a convenient solution for that. However, if you nest the dimensions properly in Beyond 20/20 browser, then convert the active window to *.csv (File --> Save As), you can work with it easily in Python (and R). Look at [this](https://support.beyond2020.com/support/solutions/articles/44001980867-converting-ivt-files-to-csv-format).